# How to send mail in xcode using ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, frameworks

Okay after finding a couple of tutorials online. Everything is okay except when the button is being pressed. I pressed the button that will sent an email and suddenly there is a signal abort. I watched two videos and re type every code in each video twice. Why is there a signal abort? Please help. Thank you!

this is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
}
-(IBAction)switchToFirst:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)openMail:(id)sender;

@end
```

this is the .m file

```
#import "secondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface secondViewController ()

@end

@implementation secondViewController


-(IBAction)openMail:(id)sender {

    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
        [composer setSubject:@""];
        [composer setMessageBody:@"message" isHTML:YES];
        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
    }
    else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"Can't send your email!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }

}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            resultLabel.text = @"Mail was sent";
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            resultLabel.text = @"Mail was saved to drafts";
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            resultLabel.text = @"Mail wasn't able to sent";
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            resultLabel.text = @"Mail was Cancelled";
            break;


    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(IBAction)switchToFirst:(id)sender {
    ViewController *second = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    // Set the background image by setting the contents of the view's layer
    UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPad iDeaf Assisstant Background.png"];
    self.view.layer.contents = (id) [bg CGImage];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

Comment: You can just remove the `retain`'s and the `release`'s...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class for email sending you can compile it without arc, just set flag **-fno-objc-arc** for files in project settings->build phases

Answer (score 0):

Like @qegal said, just take out all the `retains` and `releases.`

And if you want to keep the code you have, you can just mark files as non-arc.

To mark **any file** as non-arc you can set a compiler flag in the build phases. Select your project in the files pane on the left hand side. Then select your target, go to build phases, and double click the column underneath **compiler flags** for the file you want to mark and enter 'fno-objc-arc'.

Comment: I don't see compiler flags. I went to build phases and see compile sources. Will that still work with compile sources?

Comment: Yes where it says `compile sources`, doesn't it show `compiler flags` just to the right of it? Click the little disclosure triangle to see the `compile sources`. It should be there.

Comment: No, I don't see compiler flag. I clicked on the compile sources. Double click on the .m file and type in fno-objc-arc. T5he release errors are gone, but there is still one more error that I can't fix.

Comment: You don't actually **see** a flag, when you enter `-fno-objc-arc`, it should disable ARC, which it did. So what error are you getting?

Comment: There isn't some magical "code" that fixes all of your problems. You need to describe what your problem is. What is the error you are getting? And post some of **your own** code in your question so people can actually solve it.